# What determines transmitted and received data and why is a crossover cable and straight through cable needed in curtain situations?

Tags: networking, cable, transmission, crossover-cable

I understand what RX and TX means when it comes to networking and I understand the difference between T568A and T568B wiring standards. But the one thing I don't understand is if the different colored wires or if the individual pins determine the TX and RX.

1. What determines the TX and RX packets? Is it the wires in the cable or is it the pins on the RJ-45 plugs? This question might not be clear so I'll explain a little more. When I talk about the pins, I am asking if pin 1 is used to transmit data and pin 2 receives data. When I talk about the wires, I am asking if the green wires transmit data while orange wires receive data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand what RX and TX means when it comes to networking

Your qualifier of *"when it comes to networking"* is bizarre.  The meaning of receive and transmit doesn't change for other circumstances.

> But the one thing I don't understand is if the different colored wires or if the individual pins determine the TX and RX.

RX refers to received data, or input.
TX refers to transmitted data, or output.
These terms define direction, but these terms require a reference point.
The ports are the essential reference point.

A key concept is that not all network ports are identical.
The network port on a NIC in a PC or network printer has the role of "user terminal" (DTE), and is referred to as an **end station**.  The standard wiring for end station ports is known as MDI, Media Dependent Interface.

The port on a switch or hub has the role of "communication equipment" (DCE), and is referred to as **network device**.  The standard wiring for network device ports is known as MDIX, Media Dependent Interface with Crossover.

Certain pins of the MDI port are designated for output, i.e. TX data.
Other pins of the MDI port are designated for input, i.e. RX data.
The pins of MDIX ports are defined in the opposite manner from MDI.
This permits a straight-through cable to connect a MDI port to a MDIX port, e.g. a PC NIC to a switch.
Each output pin on one side is connected to an input pin on the other side.

But when you want to connect a MDI port to a MDI port (e.g. PC to PC), or a MDIX to MDIX (e.g. daisy-chain two switches), then you "need" to use a cross-over cable (so that receivers connect to transmitters, instead of receiver to receiver and transmitter to transmitter).  Note that Gigabit (& faster) Ethernet ports often have Auto-MDI/MDIX that eliminate the need for crossover cables.

> What determines the TX and RX packets?

A port receives (reads) RX packets on its input pins.
A port transmits (outputs) TX packets on its output pins.

If you're looking at a network cable, *"TX and RX packets"* is meaningless without designating a reference point (e.g. a client or server).

> Is it the wires in the cable or is it the pins on the RJ-45 plugs?

Seems like you're looking for a absolute answer when there is none.  It all depends on your reference point.

> When I talk about the pins, I am asking if pin 1 is used to transmit data and pin 2 receives data.

You need to identify if those pins of the port are wired for MDI or MDIX.
E.G. for a 10BASE-T port of a NIC in a PC (MDI wiring), pins 1 & 2 are for TX, and 3 & 6 are for RX.
But a 10BASE-T port of a switch or hub (MDIX wiring), pins 1 & 2 are for RX, and 3 & 6 are for TX.

[image]

> When I talk about the wires, I am asking if the green wires transmit data while orange wires receive data?

Without a reference point, it's a nonsense question.
One end (of each used) wire has the transmitter, and the other end of the wire has the receiver.
The TX signal/data that is sent from one side becomes the RX signal/data that is received at the other end.

Comment: Great answer except for the very end.  The correct answer is that electrons suffer from color blindness and are unable to discriminate the color of the insulation on the wire.  :-)