# Why do we need to use straight cables to connect 2 unlike devices?

Tags: cable, crossover-cable

First of all I know today because of Auto-MDIX  you can use any type of cable and that where you can use them, i just want to know why use them instead of other cables. a teacher asked me this question and I couldn't find a good answer so I though I ask here
the questions were:

1- Why do we need to use crossover cables to connect 2 like devices?

2- Why do we need to use straight cables to connect 2 unlike devices?

I found the answer for the first one everywhere but the second one is where i'm stuck.
I apricate it if you could help me.

Comment: I'd ask your teacher for clarification. Cross-over cables haven't really been needed in the past decade or more.

Comment: Its a bad question, but I wonder if the answer saught to both questions is to ensure sending pairs connect to receiving pairs?

Comment: Crossover cables are needed with ethernet ports that don't [auto-negotiate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation), otherwise you'd have data collisions since PC1 would be transmitting on TX,  PC2 receiving on TX, and PC2 would be transmitting on TX, PC1 receiving on TX

Comment: @Tetsujin when I asked him, he said: "everything you need to know is in the question."

Comment: @davidgo I don't think so if it was that easy he wouldn't them in sperate question. (its presented in site in two different questions)

Comment: If you look at the [wiring diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) of 10BASE-T, you'll see it's the exact same answer for both questions. What goes where if you use a straight-through cable between two hosts? What goes where if you use a cross-over cable between a host and a hub/switch?

Comment: And it _might_ be that easy – I think the intent of your teacher was to have you give an explanation derived from your understanding on how each cable connects which pairs (i.e. the actual "crossing over"), not just from rote memorization of "same device = crossover".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines transmitted and received data and why is a crossover cable and straight through cable needed in curtain situations?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311625/what-determines-transmitted-and-received-data-and-why-is-a-crossover-cable-and-s)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a network cable between 2 pc's without any aiding hardware such as a router, the cable must be crosslinked, because the network port expects the other side to have it crossed.

On most modern devices such as routers, switches, etc... the ports will simply first check the cable in crossed state, then in straight state.

Eg: When the network card sends, the router will have it in receive state. If you happen to use a cross cable, the send line would collide with the send line on the other side, but modern hardware usually corrects for this. Exceptions can be very cheap routers.

Because there are exceptions, it is simply best practice to always use a straight cable in unliked devices because that's what both ends expect, and use a cross cable in liked devices because that's what both ends expect.

By using this best practice, you get a guaranteed working situation, whereas if you don't, it may not, and you will be thinking the cable has a breach while in essence it doesn't work because the ports expect different wiring.